# Nested Accordion table icon won't change when class id set programatically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, grails, gsp

I have nested accordion bootstrap tables in a Grails .gsp page that work fine, except for the icon changing from a "+" to a "-" when collapsing/expanding.  I can get it to work if I take out the dynamic id variables and statically set the data target id instead of using data-target="#${orgs.ORGN}" and id="${orgs.ORGN}". The icon won't change when I let the g:each loop create the id's and the data, though they do collapse correctly.  Any thoughts?  Is there something about setting the id's on the fly that won't work?

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
        <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Org</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Budget</th>
                <th>YTD</th>
                <th>Remaining</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${overview}" var="orgs">
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${orgs.ORGN}" class="accordion-toggle" style="cursor:pointer">
                    <td><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></td>
                    <td>${orgs.ORGN}</td>
                    <td>${orgs.ORGNTITLE}</td>
                    <td>${orgs.BUDGET}</td>
                    <td>${orgs.YTD}</td>
                    <td>${orgs.REMAINING}</td>
                </tr>
                <td colspan="8" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="${orgs.ORGN}">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>Account</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Budgeted</th>
                                <th>YTD</th>
                                <th>Remaining</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <g:each in="${orgs.expenses}" var="budget">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${budget.ACCTCODE}</td>
                                    <td>${budget.ACCTTITLE}</td>
                                    <td>${budget.BUDGETACCEPTED}</td>
                                    <td>${budget.YTDACTIVITY}</td>
                                    <td>${budget.BUDGETREMAINING}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </g:each>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</div>
```

My JS is

```
  $('tr').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).prev('tr').find(".fa-plus-square").removeClass("fa-plus-square").addClass("fa-minus-square");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
$(this).prev('tr').find(".fa-minus-square").removeClass("fa-minus-square").addClass("fa-plus-square");
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Make sure whatever value `orgs.ORGN` is that it won't be a duplicate `id` of another HTML/dom element. That may be your issue. Inspect your HTML once it's rendered to the browser.

Comment: I have been over the DOM and the id's are unique.  I even copied the existing rendered output from Firebug and pasted into bootply and it works when pasted there.  I don't get why it won't work on its own.  Am I correct in having the JS in the .gsp's <Head> section like so:    <script type="text/javascript"> ..............
</script>

Comment: Yes, that's valid. Of course, you haven't included a full example in your question of exactly what you are doing so you could still be missing something simple. Such as not waiting for the document/DOM to be ready and trying to run your jQuery code in the head.

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to JS and I hadn't waited for the document to load like you mentioned.  I added document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() to my <script> section and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to run your jQuery code prior to the DOM being fully loaded. I'd recommend looking at the various ways to do this in the [jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Typically this is done using `$( document ).ready()`.